# Spring Data Neo4j: filter by LocalDate doesn't work

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

My small Neo4j playground application (based on Spring Boot 2, Spring Data Neo4j and the embedded driver) is a small note-keeping software. The users can filter their notes by creation date. To get a better understanding of Cypher I wrote the Cypher query using SDN's `@Query` (`NoteRepo.findByDay(day)`).

However I can't get the filtering working. I'm confused that the LocalDate was transformed into a map (last line of the console output). In the previous query (`NoteRepo.findBySnoozeUntil(day)`, using SDN's repo query keywords) everything was fine and the `day` was transformed to a ISO 8601 date.

Can somebody please point out what's wrong with it and fix it?

**Note.java**

```
@NodeEntity
class Note {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String content;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private LocalDate snoozedUntil;
    // constructors, getters, setters, ... omitted
}
```

**NoteRepo.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

interface NoteRepo extends Neo4jRepository<Note, Long> {
    // FIXME find all notes created on a specific day
    // currently returns an empty list
    @Query("MATCH (n: Note) WHERE date(datetime(n.created)) = {0} RETURN n")
    List<Note> findByDay(LocalDate day);

    List<Note> findBySnoozeUntil(LocalDate day);
}
```

**App.java**

```
package com.example.neo4jquerywithlocaldate;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        var repo = ctx.getBean(NoteRepo.class);
        var tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
        repo.save(new Note("learn neo4j", LocalDateTime.now(), tomorrow));

        var notesForTomorrow = repo.findBySnoozeUntil(tomorrow);
        System.out.println("notes snoozed until tomorrow = " + notesForTomorrow);

        var todaysNotes = repo.findByDay(LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println("today's notes = " + todaysNotes);
    }
}
```

**console output of the Spring Boot application (truncated to the Neo4j queries and System.out.println)**

```
UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`Note`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeRef=-1, props={snoozeUntil=2018-09-21, created=2018-09-20T19:38:54.732260, content=learn neo4j}}]}

MATCH (n:`Note`) WHERE n.`snoozeUntil` = { `snoozeUntil_0` } WITH n RETURN n, ID(n) with params {snoozeUntil_0=2018-09-21}

< notes for tomorrow = [Note{id=0, content='learn neo4j', created=2018-09-20T19:38:54.732260}]

MATCH (n: Note) WHERE date(datetime(n.created)) = {0} RETURN n with params {0={year=2018, month=SEPTEMBER, monthValue=9, dayOfMonth=20, chronology={id=ISO, calendarType=iso8601}, dayOfWeek=THURSDAY, era=CE, dayOfYear=263, leapYear=false}}

< today's notes = []
```

---

repro project: [Spring Initializr Project](https://start.spring.io/starter.zip?type=gradle-project&language=java&bootVersion=2.0.5.RELEASE&baseDir=demo&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&packaging=jar&javaVersion=10&autocomplete=&generate-project=&style=data-neo4j)

add this to `build.gradle`:

```
ext['neo4j-ogm.version'] = '3.1.3'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
    runtimeOnly 'org.neo4j:neo4j:3.4.7'
    runtimeOnly 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver:3.1.3'
}
```

and add the classes above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the derived queriers (one like `List<Note> findBySnoozedUntil(LocalDate day);`) are handled differently than the ones annotated with `@Query` using the embedded driver.

The embedded driver currently maps all parameters onto strings. To two this, it uses unconditionally an instance of Jacksons ObjectMapper.

We need several steps to fix this.

1. Teach ObjectMapper to use a reasonable format. That's easy, you're on Boot, so please add this starter `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json')`, it brings a lot of useful Jackson modules. If you intend to write a web application and already have `spring-boot-starter-web` or `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, you can omit the JSON starter, those modules bring it.
2. Register the included [Java 8 Jackson modules](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) with OGMs Embedded Objectmapper and disable writing dates as timestamps, i.e. in your App.class:

```java
final ObjectMapper ogmObjectMapper = org.neo4j.ogm.config.ObjectMapperFactory.objectMapper();
ogmObjectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
ogmObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

3. As the embedded driver uses this config to map the value as String, you sadly have to adapt the query:

```java
@Query("MATCH (n: Note) WHERE date(datetime(n.created)) = date({0}) RETURN n")
List<Note> findByDay(LocalDate day);
```

Related output is now

```
2018-09-24 10:50:53.313  INFO 2860 --- [           main] o.n.o.d.e.request.EmbeddedRequest        : Request: MATCH (n:`Note`) WHERE n.`snoozedUntil` = { `snoozedUntil_0` } WITH n RETURN n, ID(n) with params {snoozedUntil_0=2018-09-25}
notes snoozed until tomorrow = [com.example.demo.Note@2420e962]
2018-09-24 10:50:53.522  INFO 2860 --- [           main] o.n.o.d.e.request.EmbeddedRequest        : Request: MATCH (n: Note) WHERE date(datetime(n.created)) = date({0}) RETURN n with params {0=2018-09-24}
today's notes = [com.example.demo.Note@363d3958]
```

*Edit:* The same effect would be seen using Bolt against an external database as well, solution is currently the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is this fix somewhere documented?

Comment: Can this factory class not be replaced by an ObjectMapper bean provider? I have already had to subclass Jackson's BasicSerializerFactory to statically inject a serializer due to OGM insisting on using a vanilla ObjectMapper. Be nice if it could just use my globally defined ObjectMapper.

Comment: Also, with the ObjectMapper configuration above date({0}) should be simply {0}

Comment: Hey Dave. Thanks for chiming in. Unfortunately, the ObjectMapper is super deep involved. OGM is independent from SDN, so I cannot add a provider bean. The worse thing however is, that your 2nd comment is wrong. At the moment, OGM uses incorrectly strings to pass the stuff. We fixed that in upcoming version 3.2, which will support native types (all of them) on Bolt and Embedded in full.